# dynamic transposing contents of one table to another table's headers

Tags: microsoft-excel

There are two separate tables in the same excel worksheet. How can I achieve the following: If data is entered in any cell of any column of the table 1. The same data becomes a header of a new column in the existing table 2. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxGEz.png)

So far I'm copying the cells and using paste as transpose. Auto expand options include that in table 2 on its own. Read [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1133434/how-can-i-transpose-a-table-column-data-so-that-they-become-row-headings) here but the problem is this works for one column in table one, blank cells appear as 0,0,0,0 and the header of second table only shows 0 even if there's data in first table.

Comment: The `Headers` of a **Table** need to be plain text. So if the target needs to be a **Table**, you will need a VBA routine to automate the result.  If the order of column headers in the target is unimportant, and if it does not need to be a **real table**, you can use `=TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,originalTable) & "</s></t>","//s"))`

Comment: column order is not important in the target table. And I'm sure the formula you've provided will work but my version of excel does not have filterxml.

Comment: What version of Excel? Windows or Mac?